# How to set user main folder?

Tags: inno-setup

How to set `C:\Users\%username%` dir?
This is folder where "appdata", "my documents" etc are located.
i couldn't find this constant in inno setup documentation.
Thx in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inno Setup User Home Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656385/inno-setup-user-home-path)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for alias if yes then Just set the below one and it will work for all users.

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

Or use the below one

```
%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: DestDir: %USERPROFILE%\ ? О_о

Comment: Okey agreed Both works fine , I am updating my answer.

Comment: @user1791020, you are not supposed to write there anything in the first place. Please read the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use any environment variable:

```
ExpandConstant('{homepath}\YourPath\');
```

Comment: `{homepath}` constant doesn't exist.

Comment: It exists in Windows 7. I checked it. You can use USERPROFILE or APPDATA\..\..\

Comment: What you're thinking of is called environment variable. What you're trying to expand is a built-in Inno Setup constant that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have just compiled my project using FileExists(ExpandConstant('{homepath}\MyFile')).

Comment: It's not about compilation. The code that you've shown in your comment would execute at runtime. For how to expand environment variables see [`Constants`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) topic, specifically *Other Constants* section.