# Inno Setup constant equivalent for System.getProperty("user.home")

Tags: java, javafx, inno-setup

I'm storing a preferences file for bundled JavaFX app under user directory, which I create at Runtime using

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

I want to order InnoSetup to delete that file at uninstall, but I can't find appropriate Inno Constant. 
Please, advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, `user.home` maps to `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable, what is typically `C:\Users\username`.

There's no equivalent constant for that in Inno Setup. Probably because you are not supposed to store any files there. You should store your files to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\app` (or `...\Local\app`). In Inno Setup that is [`{userappdata}\app`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userappdata) (or [`{localappdata}\app`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=localappdata)). It Java, you can use `System.getenv("APPDATA")` (or `System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")`).

---

Anyway, to answer your question, you can use [`{%USERPROFILE}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=name).
See also [Inno Setup User Home Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17656385/850848).

---

Also in general, it's a bad idea to try to access a user profile in Inno Setup (un)installer, as the (un)installer can be executed using a different local account (typically Administrator), than the one you are interested in.

This is covered in [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848).

Comment: but how can I get "\Local\app" at Java ? Is this location ok to to access from Inno Uninstaller? Great thanks.

Comment: I do not know Java. But I assume you can use `System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")` - But any account-specific folder, including `..\Local\app` has the same problem as described in [Installing application for currently logged in user from Inno Setup installer running as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44575666/850848) - but that's a different topic.